# 'Top Tags' section overflowing into right-hand side of profile

Tags: bug, user-profile

The 'top tags' section of a User Profile overflows into the right side of the page. This happens when the tag names are too long.

[image: Top Tags]

This has a flow-on effect with the 'Newest Posts' section too:

[image: img]

This is a universal bug across browsers and operating systems.

You can [recreate it here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/267570/).

Comment: What platform is this on? I can't seem to recreate it on Windows 10, Google Chrome 88.0.4324.104

Comment: Confirmed on Windows 10, Firefox 86.0b5 at 1366 x 768. Presents a horizontal overflow bar.

Comment: I can confirm that it occurs on that user's profile (Win 10, Firefox & Chrome). I've edited the post to add additional information.

Comment: This is a universal bug its also on iOS